# Restrict awful.client.iterate to single tag

Tags: awesome-wm

What do I need to check for in the rules function to restrict the client iterator to only the focused tag?
I've tried `function(x) return x.tags == {t} end` where t is `awful.screen.focused().selected_tag` and it doesn't work.

Comment: `x.first_tag` also no go

Comment: `awful.rules.match({properties = {tags = t}})` also not working.

Comment: `==` for tables compares identity in Lua, not content. So, it will only be true if you compare a table to itself and not when the two tables have the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Just kidding, `x.first_tag == t` totally does appear to work, I had errors elsewhere.